Fourier transform of a specific type of 3-variable function that is "almost separable"
I apologize if this is basic, but I came across an engineering problem. Given a function of three independent variables of the form
$$
h(t_1,t_2,t_3)=f(t_1,t_2)g(t_1,t_3),
$$
which we know to have a Fourier transform/series. Is there anything special about the Fourier transform of $h$ that we can say that would make computing it easier or faster because of its special structure? I know if $h$ were fully separable, we could just compute the Fourier transform of each term and multiply, but I am considering a product of two functions with only one variable in common. I thank all helpers/
